# font-face not working on safari [jsfiddle example]

Tags: css, fonts, safari, font-face, google-fonts

I am loading a font with 3 weights from Google fonts, and I can display properly text in the 3 weights on Firefox and Chrome, but it won't work in Safari:

https://jsfiddle.net/vmarquet/u6ezqbrm/

Is Safari not supporting `font-face` aliases?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/7czpo2s3/

When I tested your sample, only the Regular weight displayed in Chrome and Safari. The other `@font-face` declarations you had might have been using your local copy of the font, if you have it installed, but they wouldn’t work for anyone else who doesn’t have it installed locally.

Because you are using Google Fonts, the `@font-face` declarations to use the hosted fonts are already written for you. If you go directly to [the Google Fonts URL](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700&display=swap), you’ll see you’re getting a CSS stylesheet with the `@font-face` declarations already written. The `font-family` for all the styles is Montserrat. Instead of using the different weights with the `font-family` name, you want to change it with the `font-weight`.

Here’s what I changed from your sample:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
  .light,
  .regular,
  .bold {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
  }

  .light   { font-weight: 300; }
  .regular { font-weight: 400; }
  .bold    { font-weight: 700; }
</style>

<div class="regular">Montserrat</div>
<div class="light">Montserrat</div>
<div class="bold">Montserrat</div>
```

If you do have the Montserrat font installed locally, you might also want to disable it. Then, it will be easier to tell when things are working, as Google Fonts will also use the local fonts if they are available.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I ask a specific question about `font-face` behaviour on Safari because that's currently how my site is written, and I don't want to rewrite everything with `font-weight`. You're providing an alternative way to implement the same functionality, but this is not what I ask.

Comment: @vmarquet Another option would be to download the font files from Google Fonts directly (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat), convert them to WOFF and WOFF2, self host them. Then you can use the `@font-face` declarations to name the `font-family` whatever you want (including what you already have), but obviously this takes many more steps. If you keep the hosted versions on Google Fonts, you need to use the conventional approach already provide in their CSS.